# Can i use string array to describe interface of class?

Tags: typescript

i have a class like this:

```
interface Car {
  name: string
}

class CarCollection<T extends string> {
  [K: string]: Car;

  constructor(...names: T[]) {
    for (let name of names) {
      this[name as string] = { name }
    }
  }
}
```

now i can access properties like this:

```
const collection = new CarCollection('benz', 'tesla', 'toyota')

collection.benz      // Car
collection.tesla     // Car
collection.toyota    // Car
collection.a         // undefined
collection.b         // undefined
collection.undefined // undefined
```

i'm trying to limit the properties to just those **three** (`benz`, `tesla`, `toyota`).

i tired helper `type` like this:

```
type ICarCollection<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: Car
}
```

now i have to write like this:

```
const collection: ICarCollection<'benz' | 'tesla' | 'toyota'> = new CarCollection('benz', 'tesla', 'toyota') as any
```

but i'm looking for any better way? thanks

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WPZ3qN) is a gross workaround using a static creation method.

Comment: Class declarations in TS require statically known keys; you can use a type assertion to say that a value acts as a constructor of an object with dynamic keys, like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wRROYw).  Does that meet your needs, or am I missing something?

Comment: that's actually worked for my very specific purpose. it turned out that my solution was to using the same name for the interface and the type itself :), thank you